# Develop PostgreSQL in XCode

Tags: xcode, postgresql

Some months ago I started developing on the PostgreSQL source code on a Windows machine. Developing on Windows worked like charm, especially thanks to Visual Studio.

Since I got a new Mac, I wanted to use XCode for development. However, I don't get it running with PostgreSQL:

**How do I create an appropriate project file for developing XCode on Mac and also set all targets appropriately?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>There are many different uses for PostgreSQL in XCode</strike>

1) One is to link library and start writing apps around PostgreSQL library:

http://macbug.org/macosxsample/postgresql

2) Another way would be to create iOS Apps with PostgreSQLKit:

http://www.postgresqlformac.com/lists/downloads/pgsqlkit-2/

3) Lastly various other assorted projects (including embedding the server):

http://cocoadev.com/PostgreSQL

23 Apr 2017: The newest guide is available here:
http://druware.tumblr.com/post/112163075395/getting-started-with-pgsqlkit-and-swift

Comment: the second link is not working. Is there any place I candowload it. I'm trying to connect my exsting postgresql database to swift

Comment: @toing_toing the code for PostgreSQLKit is still Objective-C, but with iSwift, you can convert it hopefully: http://iswift.org/ Here is the source to PostgreSQLKit: https://github.com/djthorpe/postgresql-kit

Comment: 2017 and none of the links above are viable any more. :(

Comment: @OwenGodfrey: I updated the answer to match the current up-to-date systems.